# How can i get tab autocomplete in maxima or wxmaxima?

Tags: fedora, autocomplete

I've heard of there being autocomplete on ubuntu, but i'm currently on fedora and there's no autocomplete when i launch maxima.

I read somewhere that this might be fixed by launching maxima with a different runtime, and i can install different maxima runtimes, but i don't know how to launch maxima with those runtimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to launch maxima with the command `rmaxima` instead of just `maxima`.

This doesn't work very well though, a lot of commands don't seem to autocomplete.

If anyone has any insights on a file i could edit somewhere to add this, or a way to fix this, that would be great.